# Lambda expression - add to collection if not present

Tags: c#, lambda

I have just started learning lambda expressions.

Is it possible to simplify the following code down further:

```
        Customer customer = Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == 3);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            customer = new Customer() { FirstName = "Ben", LastName = "Foster", ID = 3 };
            Customers.Add(customer);
        }

        // do something with customer
        customer.CreateProfile();
```

Essentially I want to check if an object exists in a collection. If it doesn't I want to create it, add it to the collection and use it later on.

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 5):

As written, it seems to be not any longer than needed for it to remain clear and readable. There are certainly hackish ways to abuse lambdas and operator `??` further here to write it all on a single line, but ultimately they only serve to obfuscate code.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably as 'simple' as you can get it, but like Pavel said, it's a bit hackish to write it on one line. Here it is anyway, just if you were curious.

```
Customer customer = Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == 3).DefaultIfEmpty(new Customer() { FirstName = "Ben", LastName = "Foster", ID = 3 });
customer.CreateProfile();
```

Comment: You'll also have to find some way to `Add()` the customer if it was newly created.

Answer (score 1):

Pavel is right. As an aside, if you're doing this in a loop, you'd want to use a HashSet or some kind of dictionary with the Id as keys in it for your search, beside your collection itself, so as not to have an O(n²) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Set implementation instead of a normal collecion.

Take a look at Iesi.Collections at http://www.surcombe.com/nhibernate-1.2/api/html/N_Iesi_Collections.htm